# How to change field size in Infor EAM?

Tags: infor-eam

How to change the size of fields in Infor EAM?
Anyone with experience with Infor EAM would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using Extensible Framework. For example, following code will change width of work order and equipment description fields if you put it in EF of WSJOBS screen.

```
Ext.define(
    'EAM.custom.external_WSJOBS', {
        extend: 'EAM.custom.AbstractExtensibleFramework',
        getSelectors: function () {
            if( EAM.app.designerMode == false) {
                return {
                    '[extensibleFramework] [tabName=HDR][isTabView=true]': {
                        afterlayout: function() {
                            try {
                                document.getElementsByName( 'description')[0].style.width = '700px';
                                document.getElementsByName( 'equipmentdesc')[0].style.width = '700px';
                                return true;
                            } catch( err) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the built in selectors in the Ext JS API. There you have the possibilities to use getOriginalFldValue(), setFieldStyle() and getFldValue().

Here is an example code to set field style, plus how you can assign a button to do some magic.

```
Ext.define('EAM.custom.external_wsjobs', {
    extend: 'EAM.custom.AbstractExtensibleFramework', 
    getSelectors: function() {
        vSelectors = {
            '[extensibleFramwork] [tabName=HDR] [isTabView=true]': {
                afterloadrecord: this.hdr_onload
            },
            '[extensibleFramework] [tabName=HDR][isTabView=true] [name=udfbutton01]': {
                click: this.button_click
            }
        };
        return vSelectors;
    },
    hdr_onload: function() {
        const vFormPanel = EAM.Utils.getCurrentTab().getFormPanel();
        const descriptionField = vFormPanel.getForm().findField('description');

        descriptionField.setFieldStyle('width:700px');
    },
    button_click: function() {
        const vFormPanel = EAM.Utils.getCurrentTab().getFormPanel();
        const workordernum = vFormPanel.getFldValue('workordernum');

        pageURL = `https://www.mypage.com/records/${workordernum}`

        window.open(pageURL, '_blank');
    }
});
```